# SQL Server Partition Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, partitioning

I have the following scenario:

```
TableA (ID GUID, Type INT) : +60M rows
TableB (ID GUID) : +5M rows
```

TableA has an Index on ID and Type
TableB the Primary Key is ID

I need to improve the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
   ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Type = 5
```

The query takes about 30 seconds to complete.

We have tried partitioning ***TableA*** on the ***Type*** column but the query execution time remains the same. Even the execution plan is still the same. As far as I understood partitioning the table should greatly improve the performance?

Do I have to adjust my query to use the partition thus increasing performance? 
Are my indexes wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are one of the people who think partitioning is a magic switch that improves performance when pressed. Partitioning mostly *reduces* performance and helps in a few narrow cases. It is mostly a management feature for bulk loading and data archiving/deletion.

Partitioning introduces *serious* consequences and cannot be done without proper understanding, planing and testing.

Create the proper indices (in your case `A(Type, ID)` would be a good start. Alternatively `A(ID) WHERE Type = 5` (a filtered index)).

Comment: You mean `A (Type, ID)`. Column `Type` is in table `A`.